# Cloud function execute successfully but notification is not received by user in flutter?

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to send notification if new document is added on "notify" collection.

I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning a promise from the function that resolves when all the asynchronous work is complete.  If you don't d that, the async work might not complete, as Cloud Functions will terminate that work early.

What you have called `userRef` is not actually a user reference.  It's a promise from the promise chain.  Return it instead:

```
return admin.firestore()
    .collection("store")
    .doc(from)
    .get()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Doug. The error is resolved but i am still not get notification

Comment: That could be any number of other issues with your client app.  Since you're not showing the code for that or explaining what you expect to happen, it's not possible to say.

Comment: That's not something we have information to verify with the information provided here.

Comment: Everything is fine in client app. I received notifications when the app is not on play store but after uploading on play store it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @Doug, Successfully sent message: { results: [ { error: [Object] } ],
  canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
  failureCount: 1,
  successCount: 0,
  multicastId: 8043765841624744000 }

Answer (score 0):

cloud functions is sent while applications in background or completely destroyed  ..
put your app in background and try to push notifications again .

Comment: whatever try what i say it must sent

Comment: you are right i will edit my comment it's called cloud functions